# Ubuntu is missing windows fonts?

Tags: ubuntu, fonts, jasper-reports

I am having a Java based web application running in Amazon EC2 Ubuntu server. I use Jasper reports to generate some reports in PDF format. I built these reports using 'Jaspersoft Studio'

Now, when I try to generate reports, I get this error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.jrfontnotfoundexception font 'Times New Roman' is not available to the jvm
```

Googled and found this is due to Ubuntu missing windows based fonts. All the posts I found on internet about this issue are pretty old. So how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I'm removing the Java tag, since this doesn't actually have to do with Java.

Answer (score 9):

Just install the Windows fonts in your Ubuntu Server. Here you have a useful [tutorial](http://catlingmindswipe.blogspot.com.es/2011/12/how-to-install-microsoft-windows-fonts.html) for it.

If you are as lazy as me, here you have this command which we'll do it entirely for you :)

`sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

In case you face any issues during installation of this package, it can be due to the fact that dpkg is locked. To circumvent this issue, restart your computer and enter this command in Terminal.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

ttf mscorefonts installer can also be installed from the packages available at the link given below.

[Download ttf mscorefonts](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ttf-mscorefonts-installer)

Comment: It says the package is not found.

Comment: @Tracer if the answer was helpful for you mark it as solution for future users in your situation :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

It downloads: Times New Roman, Anadale, Arial, Comic Sans, Courier, Georgia, Impact, Verdana, and Webdings (dingbats)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the package install for ubuntu 16.04 is broken, until this is fixed the following is a suitable workaround to solve the problem.

(1) First make sure to remove any possible old installation.

`sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer`

(2) The latest mscorefonts package (3.6) can be downloaded [here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/ttf-mscorefonts-installer/download).

(3) Now install the dowloaded package as follows:

`sudo dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer-3.6.all.deb`